# Cannot set the page file option from Virtual Memory window

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: Error]

As can be seen on the image above (see below for English Virtual Memory window for easy translation), the **Virtual Memory** window does not give me the option to **set** the highlighted hard drive to set my page file location. It should have a <kbd>SET</kbd> button to select.

Is there any way to fix this issue with the window not showing all the options, or is there a way to set the page file location and settings via command line?

Note: It does not give me any option to resize the window either.

### Side-by-Side Translated Image

- **("nenhuma" means "none")**

[image]

Comment: Your picture needs to be in English.  Be sure you attempting to change the size or location of the Page file with an Administrator account.  If this machine is on a domain then it must be a domain Administrator not a local Administrator account.

Comment: There is no way to modify my system language on the fly. But this is an administrator account, somehow a bug happened and the window got squeezed and does not allow me to resize it.

Comment: **So translate the image for us.**  Have you tried to reboot the system?  Windows 10 allows you to install any language pack you want, so you could install an English language pack, if you wanted to.

Comment: Its the same as the english image. I just want to know how to show the press button, my windows is squeezed. Its the same as this http://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Windows-10-disable-automatic-pagefile-434x600.png

Comment: I am to lazy to look on my own PC, but the question to be helpful to other people, really should have a translocation.

Comment: This must be a but in localization. I can see other UI elements are truncated too.

Comment: Have you tried using the keyboard to put focus on the Set button and press it?

Comment: Well, i havent but, even trying, i wouldnt know if i'm on the SET button etiher...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ### [Modify Pagefile Configuration from the Command Line](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/modify-pagefile-configuration-command-line)
>
> **Q: How can I change the pagefile configuration from the commandline?**
>
> **A:** This is very useful on Server Core systems where no graphical interface is required. Here I create a new pagefile on the P: volume
>   and delete the old pagefile:
>
> ```
> wmic pagefileset create name="P:\pagefile.sys"
>
> wmic pagefileset where name="P:\\pagefile.sys" set InitialSize=2048,MaximumSize=2048
>
> wmic pagefileset where name="C:\\pagefile.sys" delete
> ```
>
> Reboot the machine for the change to take effect. To list the
>   pagefiles, use the command below:
>
> ```
> wmic pagefile list /format:list
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/modify-pagefile-configuration-command-line)</sub>

---

Answer (score 2):

Depois de selecionar "Sem arquivo de paginação"(ou alguma outra opção dessas) aperta TAB do teclado(assim o sistema vai selecionar o próximo botão da tela, que é o Definir), e aperta Espaço do teclado que vai funcionar e o Windows vai perguntar se deseja isso mesmo, só confirmar, depois apertar OK e reiniciar.

Aconteceu isso comigo e resolvi assim, Windows 10 ta cheio desses bugs.

In English:
After selecting your option, press TAB to select the "Set" button, then press Space.

Answer (score 1):

> ### [How to move page file in Windows 10 to another disk](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-move-page-file-in-windows-10-to-another-disk/)
>
> 1. Press Win + R keys together on the keyboard. The Run dialog will
>      appear. Type the following in the Run box: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`
> 2. From the **Advanced** tab press the **Settings** button under the **Performance**
>      section. This will open the **Performance Options** dialog.
> 3. Switch to the **Advanced** tab and click the **Change** button under the
>      **Virtual Memory** section:
>
> [image]
>
> 4. The dialog Virtual Memory will appear on the screen. **Uncheck** the
>      option **Automatically manage paging file size for all drives**.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. From there you will be able to create the page file where ever is
>      available.
>
> <sub>[source](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-move-page-file-in-windows-10-to-another-disk/)</sub>

Comment: Its where i'm, the problem is that windows is bugging and not allowing me to resize the window to press the button SET.

Comment: Well, its what i'm trying to say. Did you see that on my image, the set button is not there but the other things are almost the same despite the language?

Comment: Is there any way to do this using command line?

Comment: My screen resolution os 1920x1080.

Comment: @MatheusSilva I added another answer for the command line method so see it.